# Force Entity Framework to recognise a TPT Inheritance Structure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, table-per-type

Given an example structure as below, Entity Framework doesn't recognise the base `Entity` inheritance, and thus doesn't map it as a TPT Inheritance between User and Entity.

```
// Where DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } is used
public class User : User<int> { }

public class User<TTest> : Entity {
    public TTest Whatever { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity {
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

I believe this is because EF will only look at the first level inheritance structure and never see the `Entity` as the base class, just that it has its properties.

So my question is, how can I force EF to recognise that Entity is indeed the base class? Just defining that User has a ForeignKey to Entity in the migration obviously isn't enough, as it still doesn't create that underlying row.

---

<strike>Bonus points: I've already noted that I can't go another level down (ie. `Employee : User`), but if you'd like to correct me on that I'll be forever in your debt also.</strike>

---

**Update**: Repro [available here on github.com](https://github.com/rudiv/EFMITest).

**Update2:** Gert Arnold's theory about not being able to map generic classes and thus breaking the chain unfortunately generated the same migration wherein `User` didn't fall through to `Entity`.

**Update3:** I can confirm that the stricken out "bonus" above does indeed work, when User maps correctly. The inheritance structure of `Entity : User : Employee` works when all 3 are tables, it is obviously not working when User can't even map back to Entity, which I believe now to be a bug in EF.

Comment: The problem is that EF can't map a generic class like `User<TTest>` .

Comment: @GertArnold I'm not trying to do so, that's why I have `User`.

Comment: Yes, but `User<TTest>` is between `Entity` and `User`, so as for EF, it breaks the inheritance chain if you want to map this as TPT.

Comment: @GertArnold Fair point - let me give it a try!

Comment: @GertArnold Nope - same issue even when `UserBase` isn't generic, it still doesn't go all the way down to `Entity`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a DbSet for each type that you want EntityFramework to add a table for, like this:

```
public virtual DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Comment: Alternatively you can also call modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>(); in OnModelCreating to get EF to pull the entity into the model.

Comment: I'm not sure where this would come from - Entities table is created and being used by others, it works fine for others. The issue is that it's not being picked up for this specific table.

Comment: Any chance you can share a complete code listing (or project) so that we can debug?